# My Internet access stopped working after restarting CentOS Linux

Tags: vmware, centos, ethernet

I have given static IP on my `Vmware` `CEntoS` virtual machine.

My internet was working fine. but after restarting machine

This is my ifcfg-eth0 file

```
DEVICE="eth0"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
#ONBOOT="no"

NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT="yes"
#BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR=192.168.0.200
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
PEERDNS="no"

DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.8.4
```

I am trying to ping the gateway 192.168.0.1 and i get

```
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.200 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.200 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

which things can cause error

UPDATE:
**I am using vmware workstation 10 on window 7 as host with bridged network state**

I tried Adding second network card in bridges mode and this is result.
etho is NAT and eth1 is bridged

```
sudo service network restart
Shutting down interface eth0:  Device state: 3 (disconnected)
                                                           [  OK  ]
Shutting down interface eth1:  Device state: 3 (disconnected)
                                                           [  OK  ]
Shutting down loopback interface:                          [  OK  ]
Bringing up loopback interface:                            [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth0:  Active connection state: activating
Active connection path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/11
state: activated
Connection activated
                                                           [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth1:  Active connection state: activating
Active connection path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/12
state: activated
Connection activated
                                                           [  OK  ]
[14:39][cento:~]$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:9E:40:3C  
          inet addr:192.168.229.130  Bcast:192.168.229.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe9e:403c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:262 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:228 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:34499 (33.6 KiB)  TX bytes:75950 (74.1 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:9E:40:46  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe9e:4046/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:168 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:22071 (21.5 KiB)  TX bytes:5598 (5.4 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:75 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:75 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:5425 (5.2 KiB)  TX bytes:5425 (5.2 KiB)
```

Comment: The host is unreachable, CentOS isn't recognising it has a network connection. Have you tried `ifup eth0` and/or `service network start`?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler  , i have updated the question . i tried adding new network card from workstation and then i get this. i still have not got ip on `eth1`

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure what kind of network mode your guest is in. It is NAT mode by default,so the IP address should be got from a DHCP server, A.K.A the virtual adapter in your host machine. So you may comment all the configuration about static IP, and set it to DHCP mode, then restart your adapter.

Comment: The mode is bridged , and ip is static , i tried resyrating vm , host , network , there is no firewall. it only hapopened after my computer shutdown unexpectedly

Comment: try this [my reference](https://gist.github.com/lovelock/6972933). If you want to use /etc/resolv.conf then PEERDNS

Comment: i ahve seen that if i choose NAT then my internet works but if i choose bridged then it dont work. i am using vitrual box on same compuer with bridged config is that can be the case

Comment: Now I have the answer. When in bridge mode, your guest should be configured as your host because they are in the same net, so check your host's configuration first.

Comment: i didn't get , what do i need to cehck in host confgi

Comment: Yes, in bridge mode, **the NETMASK and GATEWAY must be the same with your host**, e.g, your host's IPADDR=192.168.17.11, then your guest's IPADDR may be 192.158.17.12 or something like that instead of 192.168.0.200 if your NETMASK is set to 255.255.255.0.

Comment: I have updated my question . i tried adding new network card

Comment: So, where is your ifcfg-eth1? Have you tried my solution?

Comment: currently i have dynamic ip address setting in . i coped ifcfg-eth1 from ifcfg-eth0

Answer (score 0):

try this [my reference](https://gist.github.com/lovelock/6972933)
I haven't seen `DNS1=8.8.8.8` here before, if you want to use /etc/resolv.conf then `PEERDNS="no"`, if you want to overwrite /etc/resolv.conf then `PEERDNS="yes"`, However, in both situations there is no `DNS1= item`.

Comment: that setting worked for me for many months without anny issue

Comment: Well, sorry about that, then I should expect another man to help us out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure an interface configuration for eth1. Take the configuration you posted and save it as ifcfg-eth1. Change the DEVICE line to match eth1 and make sure you configure an IP address that is unused.